# Identify chip TM39FC

Tags: power-electronics, identification

I've searched all over. Can anyone help me ID this six-pin chip?

It's from an [LCD controller board like this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265968457425?hash=item3decf496d1:g:sd8AAOSwGwNjYqOE&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8DFAmiq6frrpG%2FQLWOShlMVFVmWoELGZj4OuCyab%2FTq9q%2FMqtfSy7IFwrZy4f4u74Ck2zlu8%2FDaygwYgIpGjSjumTMWorBd0ua%2FT5kCfmegxv%2BVu0VmQqtvKj4OsqD2aoKVPlpx%2ByBsac%2BdzrH1LcVLzHxbP8M6nCMF97MNGrE%2BC2uLU3WdYZ5HXrQj47sJUbYvZM2NAuEiWIZCb2XW0%2F5tDPNi3IRQq9zpMj1Qb7EZijf9kSFSWSIj0RPFodUzztmwWJGdeHzsCpuWypAY5f5A%2FjduA52whLJGbMXJ7I3L7cygUWLFI%2F4U28SPH0znFhA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBM-L2ks4ph), and I believe it's part of the LED backlight driver, since I accidentally reversed the 12v DC input and fried it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the marking is TM35FC? From the (blurry) photo it looks like TM39FC.  I couldn't find any reference to a 6-pin SMT device with top marking beginning with TM.  Can you trace out the circuit and draw a partial schematic?  That might narrow down the possibilities.  Looks like it might be a SOT-363?   Can you measure the dimensions?

Comment: Welcome ... I don't see any 6-pin devices on the boards you posted.  Do you have another picture?